# Space in command line php argument called from linux script

Tags: php, bash

I have this script in Ubuntu where I call the file load.php and I want to pass the argument $filexml

```
#!/bin/bash
...
filexml="/Program Files/myfile.xml"
./load.php $filexml
```

The file load.php is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
echo $_SERVER['argv']['params'][1];
exit;
```

But the result is incomplete because it takes the parameter until the space in /Program Files/ directory. Like this:

```
$/Program
```

Please help :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same solution as always.

```
./load.php "$filexml"
```